# Javascript to add opacity to a button image when checkbox not ticked

Tags: javascript

New to Javascript and I have a need to make a button unclickable unless a checkbox has first been selected.

I achieved that by using the following javascript function found on SO.

```
$(function() {
  var chk = $('#post_offers-checkbox');
  var btn = $('#btncheck');
  chk.on('change', function() {
    btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

This works perfectly to prevent click on the button. However, I want to make it more obvious that the button isn't active by adding opacity unless the checkbox is selected.

So I tested this line to add into the function

```
$('.grey-out').css("opacity", "0.5");
```

What I can't figure out is how to get it to only apply opacity when the button is also inactive.

I tried this

```
$(function() {
  var chk = $('#post_offers-checkbox');
  var btn = $('#btncheck');
  chk.on('change', function() {
    btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    ($('.grey-out').css("opacity", "0.5"), !this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

but that didn't work.
I also tried

```
$(function() {
  var chk = $('#post_offers-checkbox');
  var btn = $('#btncheck');
  chk.on('change', function() {
    $('.grey-out').css("opacity", "0.5")    
    btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

HTML

```
<fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" name="post_offers" value="1" id="post_offers-checkbox" /><label class="checkboxLabel" for="post_offers-checkbox">From time to time we’d like to send you our latest catalogues, promotions and special offers by post. If you want to receive these, please tick this box</label><br class="clearBoth" />
</fieldset>

<div class="buttonRow forward grey-out"><input type="image" src="includes/templates/0701/buttons/english/button_send.gif" alt="Send Now" title=" Send Now " id="btncheck" /></div>
```

But that didn't work either.

I'm lost! How on earth do I make it behave the way I want?

Comment: Can you add your html

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Added to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if button is disabled or not with

```
$("#btncheck").is(":disabled")
```

And then add `css` like

```
  if($("#btncheck").is(":disabled")){
      $("#btncheck").css("opacity", "0.5")
    }else
         $("#btncheck").css("opacity", "1")
```

So your final code would look like

```
chk.on('change', function() {
    btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
     $("#btncheck").is(":disabled") ? $("#btncheck").css("opacity", "0.5") : $("#btncheck").css("opacity", "1")
  }).trigger('change');
```

Comment: That works perfectly. So the mistake i made was trying to use the existing check, rather than adding another for the css change. Thank you. Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.checked 
example: 
html :

```
<button id="button">test</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkbox").on('click', function() {
         this.checked ? $("button").css("opacity", 0.5) : $("button").css("opacity", 1);
    });
});
```